# Deeplink Angular Virtual Routes

Tags: angular, apache, routes

In an Angular SPA I have installed deeplinks. You can also jump to them from the application, but if I type the url directly into the browser I get a 404 error. I am aware that Angular only builds virtual routes and that these are not physically located on the ApacheServer.

Specifically, the following route:

```
<domain>/app/hamburg/energy
```

The application is located in the folder "app".

I use the following RewriteRule in the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On  
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

I need the deep links for the search engine optimization of the application. Can someone help me and explain how I can jump directly to the subpages of the application via the links?

Many greetings and many thanks.

Sascha

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# To be inside the /Directory
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```